# Is there a way to list all active sprint names on all projects in the jira instance

Tags: jira

I want a list of all active sprints in jira from all projects.  As admin there are times when a scrum master does not start the sprint on time and I need a way to identify those team's that are delayed.

I need query like below, just an example
Select sprint name from all Jira projects where active sprint is true

Answer (score 0):

1- You can create and save a filter that get all the issues that are in an open Sprint. The JQL is : **Sprint in openSprints()**.

2- Create a new board that uses the filter created in step 1.

3- Open the board and go to the Backlog view to see a list of all the open Sprints and the issues in the Sprints.